# Playback and listen to recording device in FMOD

Tags: windows, audio, recording, playback, fmod

Is it possible to simultaneously playback the recording device by using the FMOD api? This functionality would be the same to what Windows offers in the recording device properties where you can enable "listen to this device" for certain recording devices. If this isn't possible via FMOD, is there another API more suited for this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with FMOD by simply recording with looping set to true, then play the recorded sound as looping also. Providing you separate your recordStart call and your playSound call by some time (say 10ms) the play cursor and the record cursor will follow each other and you will get realtime playback.

There is an example of this with the "recording" example that ships in the FMOD API for most platforms and there is a more advanced example on the Windows platform that shows adding realtime effects to a live recorded sound.

Comment: Thanks! That's definitely what I wanted to do. Unfortunately, either the quality of the recording or the quality of the playback is very poor. It is coming through the speakers at a lower quality than I would like to use. I've been trying to change some of the configurations in the example but nothing has made much of a difference. Oh well, I will play around with it some more!

Comment: The two main things that affect quality of the recording are the sample rate and the format (i.e. PCM16, PCM8 etc). You can control both of these via the FMOD_CREATESOUNDEXINFO structure you pass into System::createSound. Setting these to 44100 and PCM16 should get decent quality results. Also, if you are on Windows Vista or Windows 7 check the properties of your microphone, ensure that the sample rate and format in there are the same.